# Merge whole program with my C# project

Tags: c#, powershell, vmware, powercli

I want to created and app which uses VMware ovftool, but the app needs that ovftool installed on each PC that you want to use. Most of the computers in my office does not have that ovftool installed, so I started to wonder if there is way to import/include/merge the ovftool to my C# project and to access it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Write an installer ([WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/) will do it all, but has quite a steep learning curve), and make sure that any prerequisites are installed with your app.